# Unknown Tokenizer: icu in sqlite3 request

Tags: iphone, sqlite, fts3

Help me, please, with a problem. I have a virtual table in my sqlite database:

```
`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tablename USING fts4(column1, column2, tokenize=icu ua_UA)`
```

When I try to make an SQL query to this table like

```
const char *sql = "SELECT column2 FROM tablename WHERE tablename.column1 MATCH ?";
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [matchString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

I'm getting the next error from database: Error: 'unknown tokenizer: icu'.
I've downloaded sources of sqlite, added sqlite.c into my project in xCode4 and added #define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 into sqlite.c file. But the problem still exist.
I'm Trying to do it in the Simulator, may it be the cause?

Help me, please. How can I handle with FTS4 on iPhone with xCode 4? Should I use some ancient magic? :)

Have a good time!

Answer (score 2):

You also need to recompile the sqlite library itself, with `SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU` #defined.

It's not enough to just add the source file and the option in Xcode, because the sqlite library will not be recreated.

See [Tokenizers](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer) in the ICU docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with this feature but I know it is an extension to sqlite, http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/fileview?f=sqlite/ext/icu/README.txt - it sounds like it's not installed here. HTH